# What happened to my edit?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I spent so much time carefully updating [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541804/257299). But now the edit is gone. What happened?

EDIT:
Also, if my edit is rejected, where can I find an original copy?  I don't see a link from the page to see past edits.

Comment: It was rejected by 3 reviewers: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1610610

Comment: Stack Overflow is not Wikipedia.

Comment: This looks like it could be an answer of its own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1610610) because it was a radical change and it was an invalid change. As told in [the edit guides](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) you should edit for reasons like this:

> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

You made a radical change by extending the current answer with a lot more information. You should (a) create a new answer to the question, refering to the current answer and saying the information you want or (b) you should post it as a comment (linking to some code dump site, because you can't use that much code in a comment). Use *b* if you it is more a sort of 'sidenote' and use *a* if it is important and relevant to the question.

Answer (score 14):

You [suggested an edit on an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1610610) which was rejected by community. Because it was a radical change in an answer. Instead of suggesting edit you should add your own answer.

---

**Edit:**
Any rejected edit is not appear in the post. But you can find all your suggested edit in your [activity tab -> suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257299/kevinarpe?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: +1: post your info as a separate answer!

Answer (score 3):

On stack overflow you currently have 762 rep. As per the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation):

> 2000   Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits

As this tells you, you don't have rep to make edits right now that will "take" right away. This also implies what happened, others (with 2K+ rep) rejected your suggested edit.

If you look around meta you'll see a lot of questions regarding suggested edits and why they may be rejected, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142155/why-was-suggested-edit-rejected) for example.

The primary reason [your edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1610610#./1610610?&_suid=1361972574751023623907865789628) was because it was an invalid edit/drastic change. You doubled the size of the post. When you change an edit this drastically, it's a good bet that you could (and should) just make a new answer out of it.

Comment: I can be wrong, but there is only one person voting for 'drastical change' and 2 for 'invalid edit', which means it was rejected because it was an 'invalid edit'.

Comment: @WouterJ - no, you are correct about that I just skimmed the change, updated it. Thanks.