# Proper definition of "correct minor mistakes"

Tags: discussion

The only formal guideline, as far as I could find, for editing post was stated on the page where you actually are making the edit and one of the guidelines states *"correct minor mistakes"*.

So the question is that, what constitute as a *minor mistake*? (Of course in SO's context)

Comment: Spelling errars; misplaced, punctuation such things.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin': You forgot typ0s

Comment: Spelling errors and grammatical mistakes are listed separately from "minor mistakes" on the privilege page, so I'd be interested to know what they'd actually encompass too.