# What do I do when I see code edits being approved?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, suggested-edits

I'm witnessing code edits [which is highly discouraged by the Stack Overflow community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179656/221866) is being approved.

E.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3749987) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3742292).

Should we be worried about this? And what should be done, except rollbacks which might give-up the good parts of the edit and otherwise time consuming?

Comment: I only encountered this once and reverted the edit, as edits should be neutral and not modify a question so that the question is drastically changed, which also includes keeping typos or invalid characters intact. On answers AFAIK this is ok.

Comment: fix it (be editing or rolling back), then @- the editor telling them not to do that

Comment: I would have approved the first change without any qualms, and I would have rejected the second not because it was code but because it was radical.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Then I guess we need to rethink and discuss our policies on code edits.

Comment: I do a fair amount of suggested edit reviewing, and I don't think there's a big problem.  At least, not that I've seen.  There are occasionally edits that get through that I would have rejected (usually 'too minor' but it was already approved by the time I'd hit reject), but I don't go and roll those back.  The edit is 'fine', but wasn't worthy of 2 points.  If the approved edit is more substantively wrong, then I'll go fix it. I don't go back and verify that every code change I reject is rejected by others.

Comment: @BleedingFingers The post that you linked to in the OP has a net score of 0, which is comprised of 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes.  I don't think that's enough to be considered "community policy"

Comment: If I saw the 2nd edit I'd roll it back and copy the edit into the question - which was the intention of the commenter who requested clarification. The first edit I'd just skip (i.e. accept that it's going to get approved, but unsure I deem it worthy)

Answer (score 14):

There's nothing magical about code edits that makes them intrinsically better or worse than edits outside code.

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3749987) reformats the code in a question. It is usually a bad idea to edit code in questions, because you might inadvertently fix the problem that the question was about. However, improving the indentation or wrapping long lines (in languages that aren't sensitive to such changes) is good. In this case, the edit did a bit more than wrap long lines — it did what was necessary to split a long string literal across multiple lines, and changed the case of some SQL keywords. Splitting across multiple lines was a good edit, and you should not revert it. Changing the case was unwarranted, but not wrong, it's a matter of style — an edit that does only this should be rejected, but there's no call for reverting it either. So on the whole this was an acceptable edit (even if it would have been better to leave the case alone). If you see this in a review queue and are unsure that the changes respect the program's semantics (for example because you don't know that SQL keywords are case-insensitive), skip it.

[This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3742292) is a bad one and should have been rejected, but not intrinsically because it changed code — it would have been the same if the edit hadn't introduced any code. This edit was the asker adding material regarding her question to an answer, in response to this answer. She should have edited her question instead. This edit should have been rejected as “invalid edit” (“is (…) an attempt to reply”), or better with custom guidance (“please edit your question instead”). You were right to roll it back. You should have moved the material to the question while you were at it.

Comment: By the way, while I agree with you that *There's nothing magical about code edits that makes them intrinsically better or worse than edits outside code*, you should be aware, if you're not already, that most of the community takes completely the opposite view. [Robert Harvey ♦ opines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201618) that *there is almost zero justification for changing code in a question*, and [this proposed FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200342) says that code in questions 'should' not be made at all except for formatting changes. Barely more is permitted for answers.

Comment: @MarkAmery Where do you get that “most of the community takes completely the opposite view”? There's no majority, even on MSO, that states that editing code *in answers* is somehow intrinsically bad. There's a majority that states that editing code *in questions* is (almost always) bad, but I am part of that majority.

Comment: I'm going by the (+43 / -3) votes on the proposed FAQ entry stating that code edits in answers should be limited to fixing syntax errors, typos and formatting, and which also (at least by my interpretation - you may read the 'indentation changes are allowed' guidance more liberally) advises against the question code edit you've just addressed in this answer and described as good.

Comment: @MarkAmery Where on earth are you reading that? I see “ Unlike questions, making an answer work is a good thing and should be encouraged with a few guidelines to follow. Do: Test your edited code to make sure it works (…) Don't: [conspicuous lack of ‘edit code’]”

Comment: Ugh... you're completely right, I'm misunderstanding what I'm reading. I was taking the "Do:" list as an exhaustive list of permissible types of code edit, with everything else being implicitly discouraged and the "Don't:" list just being a list of common bad things that were worth explicitly instructing people to avoid. Now that you say otherwise, though, I think that things that fall outside either the "Do:" or "Don't:" list are meant to implicitly fall under "Use your own judgement" rather than "Don't". Apologies for what I now think is just my lack of reading comprehension.

Comment: Changing the case of some SQL keywords? Please don't encourage the must uppercase everything brigade. It's really annoying, impossible to read, and they do it to my answers as though they're doing me a favour. If your only edit is to randomly uppercase words in a post, please don't. Making more of the post visible is fine, but I would have rejected that edit.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards You're right, I should have made it clear that the two aspects of the edit are different. I've edited my answer. I would still accept the edit because it breaks the long line, but I do agree that it would have been better if the edit left the case alone, and I would have rejected an edit that only changed the case.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles, it's appreciated :-).

Answer (score 5):

The first example, while it is a code edit, is also a non-functional change.  It's changing the casing of SQL code, which is case insensitive, and also changing it so that it wraps instead of scrolling horizontally.  In general I'd say that these changes (in particular, the changing of the case) is a matter of personal preference, and as such shouldn't be made as an edit to another's post.  I would say it should be rejected, but it isn't *super* worrying to me.  I wouldn't waste my time rolling back such a change unless they made a mistake in editing that functionally changed the code.

The second example isn't so much the fact that it's code, but rather that it's a radical change as it's another user adding their own unique content, rather than simply enhancing the author's content.  It should be rolled back.  Consider posting a comment to the editor indicating that it is not the appropriate use of editing.  Flag for a mod if it is edited again, rather than getting in a rollback war.

Comment: Did @ tell the editor in the second case.

Comment: Formatting to remove the scroll bar can be useful in making the question/answer easier to understand if you don't have to keep scrolling to see everything.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, Note that the 2nd example was edited by the OP, rolling back feels to me a bit like barging into a conversation.

Comment: @JoeW Yes, but it does still fall under stylistic code changes in my eyes, and while I personally find it annoying, I recognize that I can't change everyone's code to be in line with my styles.

Comment: @Leeor The edit was improper; that it was the OP doesn't give them the right to add entirely new content into an answer.  In this case, it should have been an edit to the OP (it was an answer to a clarifying question).  The comment by the person doing the rollback made that clear, so the OP edited the question.  It would also have been appropriate for the person who rolled back the edit to go and edit that content into the question, in this case.

Comment: @Servy, I agree, but would still avoid enforcing something between an OP and the one answering him/her. I think a simple comment to the OP would have been enough.

Comment: @Leeor Rolling back an inappropriate edit is an appropriate action.  It doesn't matter whether it's made by an OP or not.  Many people asking questions are newer users, or users otherwise not familiar with how things are done on this site. The design of the community moderation is that you can correct (many) such actions when you see them, you don't need to just ignore them and leave them for someone else to fix. If it personally bothers you to make such an edit, you you're not *obligated* to make it, but it's certainly not wrong for someone else to make such an edit; it is the correct action.

Comment: @Servy  Sorry, I was confused.  At first I thought that the linked edit was the question itself, and that somebody else had edited the code away from the answer and into the question, which in my opinion would be entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

### Not All Code Edits are Discouraged

Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code to understand when code edits are appropriate, and when they aren't.

### What Should I Do If I See a Bad Edit Get Accepted?

Rolling back the edit is a good start. You can link them the above FAQ and inform the editor with an `@ping` comment to let them know why you did so.