# Why were my edits on an answer rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I tried twice (sorry, didn't see the first rejected edit) to edit an answer that had a small typo and a small "bug". The "bug" was that a parameter is passed to the function but never used in it.

However, they were rejected by the community :

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2304606

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2451513

I read that "Edits are meant to-

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
- to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
- to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
- to add related resources or hyperlinks

I believed this was what I attempted to do. I don't think my edit changed the content of the answer.

Any insight on what was wrong with the edit would be appreciated.

Comment: Functional edits to the code are often rejected by the community (but often accepted by the OP). The community can't guarantee that the OP wanted the code to do this so they reject

Comment: Situations like this are better handled by leaving a comment explaining what you think the code change should be.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142155/why-was-suggested-edit-rejected?lq=1, as well...

Comment: Declarative sentences end in one period. There is no space between the last word in a sentence and the punctuation mark. "sry" and "thx" are not words. Please take care of your own posts before trying to edit other people's answers.

Comment: WOW ! So constructive as answer...Thx for nothing !

Comment: @FabienTheSolutionRacine "**Thanks** for nothing". I'm sorry but it is a legitamate comment, this is a professional site, not myspace

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle corrections to answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186749/how-to-handle-corrections-to-answers)

Comment: @FabienTheSolutionRacine If you don't thing using appropriate spelling/grammar and a quality formal writing style is appropriate then you're going to have problems using the site, much more so if you plan to edit other's posts.  If you plan to be sarcastic and combative when someone is trying to help you then you'll have that much more trouble here.

Comment: edit others' posts... ;)

Comment: My edits was not grammar or spelling error. I'm a french native speaker so I will not try to fix those kind of errors. Sorry but it's also my first question. And again WOW! Getting trouble! Thanks! Be sure, I will leave your small world alone with this kind of answer.

Comment: Your English is excellent for a non-native. But abbreviations like "thx" are not welcome in this community - Im also sure whoever taught you English didnt teach you these sort of abbreviations.

Comment: `WOW ! So constructive as answer...Thx for nothing !` All things considered, I have to admit, I do think that's funny.

Comment: @Richard Tingle...I think you mean "legitimate comment"...:) Review yourself before doing this kind of comment.

Comment: @FabienTheSolutionRacine This can only go downhill from here.

Comment: Fabien, you should understand that no one is here to attack you and that you should not take the posts personally. Almost everyone here is a volunteer, and many have committed considerable time and effort to making the community what it is today. Personal attacks and emotions don't really have a place; the commentors are merely trying to help you understand how the site works and to help you avoid pitfalls that will make your experience less enjoyable.

Comment: Despite your righteous indignation, we *are* trying to be helpful here.  You wouldn't like it very much if we butchered *your* native language.

Comment: @nickhar While we're discussing the title would it make sense to edit in "Why were my edits to the code on an answer rejected?" to make it more long term useful? I was considering it but the body does talk about a a bug **and a typo**

Comment: @BilltheLizard: You're not gonna believe this: *"[Teach pupils to text in a foreign language with our exciting new txt spk resource packs. Packs available in English, French, German, Spanish and Welsh.](https://www.routesintolanguages.ac.uk/txtspk)"*

Comment: @Robert Oh dear lord. Say it ain't so.

Comment: @George Cummins I understand this. But answer like "Please take care of your own posts before trying to edit other people's answers." is a little bit rude and look like a "personnal attack" on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Fabian, the post you were editing has lots of grammatical problems. Your edit changed the code, which as we say, isn't generally accepted. It didn't touch the grammatical errors. That's a problem - we'd prefer that suggested edits focus on cleanup, and handle most, if not all, of the problems present.

Comment: @Fabien I understand why it feels that way, which is why I asked that you look at the bigger picture. Almost everyone involved (here on Meta more so than elsewhere) is trying to make sure that the site is as helpful as possible to as many people as possible. It is for that reason that personal responsibility was advocated. I am sorry if that feels like a personal attack, but I am sure that it wasn't meant in that way. The only goal is to make sure that all posts (yours, ours, and others) are as clear and helpful as possible within the site rules.

Comment: (To vainly try to bring this back on topic) It would be good if the OP could retrospectively approve these sorts of code-editing edits (as they ultimately know if that was what they ultimately meant) as per this feature request http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157852/allow-the-owner-of-a-post-to-approve-a-suggested-edit-even-if-it-was-rejected-by

Comment: So I understand that this kind of edit is more appropriate in comment. But now I have another question...How I can comment this answer? I don't see any link to "comment"...only share and edit command? Do I need to have a minimum of reputation to comment?

Comment: 50 rep is required to comment everywhere - though you can always comment on your own posts.
FWIW, I would reject an edit which fixed some issues with the post, but did not fix glaring grammar and spelling errors.  Edits should be **substantive**, because they are seen by so many people.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As soon as an english person try to talk or write in french, I like it, even if he does mistakes :)

Comment: N'importe qui peut écrire en français de nos jours.

Comment: You are not living in Montreal :)

Comment: @KatieK I just tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2473973 with no success. And since you said that I need to have 50 rep to comment, I assume that is why I got this kind of comment "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post."

Comment: @FabienTheSolutionRacine - I think you're correct - the edits to the code should be *suggested* to the author via a comment.  When you get more rep, you'll be able to comment.  Also, please note the edits that I've made the to post - I fixed multiple issues.

Comment: @KatieK Just to let you know, and to everybody, that I got enough rep to comment on that answer and the person who post it fix it according to my suggestions. I knew I was right :) It's "dull" that I wasn't able to fix something for the benefit of everyone at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional edits to the code are often rejected by the community (but often accepted by the OP). The community can't guarantee that the OP wanted the code to do this so they reject since changing the function of the code (even to function better) is to change the original meaning of the post. Fixes that correct simple compiler errors etc are usually accepted however (eg a missing semi colon at the end of a line in java).

Generally code improvement should be a comment not an edit

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, approving edits is done by people who often don't have any knowledge of the subject matter.  It's much better to post answer changes that involve actual code (not just formatting) as comments, and encourage the original poster to modify the answer; otherwise it would be very hard for approvers to verify the edit (as if it's an edit to some C#, and the reviewer is a HTML/CSS guru, he/she may well have no idea if you need a semicolon there or not).

This is also true for questions, although to a lesser extent; it's somewhat more permissible to make a functional change to a question, as long as its intent is clarification.  Code in questions still should not be changed (in particular as that's often the problem in the first place!) and those changes should be in comments or in an answer (if that's the problem with the OP's code).