# Edit post privilege revoked

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I gained the "suggest edit" privilege and badge yesterday. Today I edited code in some questions. But suddenly I found that I am unable to edit any post any more.

When I will get edit-suggesting privileges back?

Comment: 5 out of 6 suggested edits have been rejected, and you've been blocked for one week.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2449215) is definitely too minor, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2440871) is a change that is too invasive: it changes the answer instead of just making it easier to understand.

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to *avoid* editing code in other posts. Leave a comment instead. Most definitely do not change the meaning of code in other answers.

Comment: [One of your suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2447473) only replaced all the double quotes around strings with single quotes. Javascript supports both, so using one over the other is only a matter of personal preference. What did you think that edit would achieve?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: It also added a missing quote. My guess is that the other quote changes were there just to pass the minimum change requirement. Which is in and of itself a sign the edit should have been left to the OP or to someone with 2k+ rep.

Comment: @Martijn, ah, you're right, I missed that. Still, why change the quote type? (Bypassing the minimum change requirement was not the answer I was looking for ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: when added missing quote and tried to submit edit, it said me to edit atleast 6 characters, then what would I do, so to edit code I replaced other 5 double quotes to single quotes, which finally edit 6 characters. :)

Comment: I would almost say [this might come in handy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187493/add-info-to-the-help-center-stating-what-not-to-edit) @MartijnPieters ;)

Comment: @Bart: Yup, already aware of that post. :-)

Comment: Also, the question for which the edit which was successful meant the question (and your answer) no longer make sense - I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you gain your privilege back, make sure to read the whole Help page on the topic. And I'll quote the most relevant part on what makes a good edit:

> ### [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)
>
> > #### When should I edit posts?
> >
> > Common reasons for edits include:
> >
> > - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> > - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> > - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> > - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> > - To add related resources or hyperlinks

When editing a post, try to fix **everything** you can.

You can also learn by inspecting the edit history of Q&A's from your area of interest. Looks like it's ASP.net: here are [the most voted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net?sort=votes&pagesize=50) and probably heavily edited.

Answer (score 15):

You are banned from making edit suggestions for 7 days, because too many of your suggested edits were being rejected. The measure exists to make you stop and reevaluate what you are doing.

Specifically, [5 out of 6 of your suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/928786/chirag-vidani?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) have been rejected.

Some suggestions for avoiding that in the future:

- Do not change code, especially not the *meaning* of code. Fixing a missing quote is one thing, changing class names is entirely different. Most reviewers will reject such edits.
- Fix more than just a missing quote or a broken link. Suggested edits should be more substantial, fix grammar, spelling, improve formatting across the *whole* post.

Comment: Even fixing a missing quote is dangerous - it's possible that error exists with the OP's code and is causing problems.