# Reviewing edit where code has been corrected

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have noticed some users are approving suggested edits where the editor has changed the code of the post, to correct it. [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2467932) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2467950)

I thought that posts should not have code corrections as such, but instead be downvoted and, possibly left a comment.

In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300396/copying-a-triangular-area-from-one-picture-to-another-in-python/) I have downvoted the answer, left a comment, and provided an answer that does not plagiarize the existing answer.

Comment: Something tells me [we could use some clarification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187493/add-info-to-the-help-center-stating-what-not-to-edit)... <--- no self-promotion to see here people... ;)

Comment: @Bart lol, good idea.. when I have finished this term of Uni I will look at contributing like this ;) the only reason I stumble upon these quirks is, SO is my lifeline.. I'm either seeking help from it, or escaping my responsibilities on it !! hahahahahhaha (yeh like how I added a link to my answer - no self- promotion there either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that, on answers, there's a little more lenience as far as code edits go.

The justification for question code edits is that said bad code could be present in their actual code. However, with answers, this doesn't make much sense. Minor edits like this can be approved, to a very limited extent.

I personally don't mind someone changing `Sting` to `String`. Additionally, the capitalization issue is... not really all that relevant. I may have improved the edit to remove the capitalization changes, but when it comes down to it, there would be no difference.

I would likely have approved this edit. However, if there were no active suggested edit, I would likely just have commented. Downvoting is particularly important for entirely wrong answers, which this isn't. The author could just correct this.

If you see someone make a significant change to the code of a question or answer, and (for some reason) the suggestion is approved, feel free to roll it back, since it's not a valid edit.

Comment: yes, I think I should provide another example as well, as this example does not demonstrate this issue in the best way

Answer (score 1):

> posts should not have [code] corrections, but instead be downvoted and, possibly left a comment.

While this may be true for questions (the faulty code may be the cause of the error OP is asking about), I don't see why you couldn't replace `sting` with `string` in an answer where appropriate.

I find the uppercase to lowercase conversion of the strings in the suggested edit a bit weird though, and given the age of the edited answer I'd have rejected it as too minor, but changing code in answers certainly can be acceptable.

Comment: The uppercase => lowercase _is_ too minor, but you shouldn't throw out  the baby (typo fix) with the bathwater (minor extra edits)

Comment: @JanDvorak what do you mean? throw the baby out with the bath water.. like in reference to what in particular?

Comment: Given the context, an old question with plenty of answers, an accepted answer and an edit on one of the many non-accepted answers without upvotes, a **single letter was added** where any ~~programmer~~ copy-paster would spot within a few seconds that an `r` was missing. The uppercase-lowercase probably was to hit the edit treshold. @Yve it means that the greater cause (a perhaps useful edit) should not be rejected because the edit may also contain useless parts. But that's what we have the Improve button for.

Comment: @CodeCaster ah, right. I didn't look at the edit in the context of the question. Yeah, that answer was probably not going to be seen by anyone.

Comment: And when reviewing, I could not see how many other answers there were, or can I?

Comment: @Yve no, but it's (imho) the entire context that counts. Fixing one typo in an non-upvoted answer that is older than a few days I think is too minor. This isn't english.stackexchange.com, and by approving such an edit you're approving the (imho) bad behaviour of applying minor, rather irrelevant changes to old post.

Comment: @CodeCaster english.stackexchange? huh oh you mean fixing up one typo?? man I g2g2 bed it's 4.48am