# Badge for successful reopening of closed questions

Tags: discussion, badge-request

There can be a badge for user who vote for reopening of questions quite often and the question actually gets reopened. This can be a good idea as questions which were closed due to bad title or other faults will get reopened after being edited.

I do not know what can be the name for such a badge. But would it not be appropriate to have such a badge?

Have a **bronze badge** if the 20% or some percentage of the reopen voted questions get reopened and similar silver and gold badges.

Comment: No, I don't think there is a need for such a badge.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Fair enough. I just thought it can be nice as closed questions will get attention if there is a scope for improvement.

Comment: We really need a rush of bad, closed question being reopened, so people can earn a badge.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I gave you an upvote for the thought and research into this question, even though I don't think it's a good idea

Comment: @Yve Thanks. I would love to contribute to the community in some way and that's why just put a thought in this. Doesn't matter if I got downvoted. Will keep trying to come up with something valuable. :)

Comment: @NarendraPathai go through my questions, seriously, I don't know how I have positive rep here, I have so many good and bad posts, and some (you can't see the breakdown) that have a net vote close to zero are split with lots of up and down votes, so NO, don't give up ;) I saw all your downvotes and thought, well the idea has merit, but maybe needs a little tweaking ;)

Answer (score 1):

When I first read the title of this question, I thought you were suggesting that we award a badge to users whose questions are re-opened after being put on hold. I think that badge might actually be a good idea ([looks like it's been proposed already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70061/i-propose-changing-the-term-closed-out-for-something-else/109362#109362)). *That* is the kind of behavior that we would like to encourage—taking constructive criticism, editing your question, and improving it to fit our standards. But I guess you could say getting your question re-opened and getting an answer is reward enough?

What you are actually proposing here (giving a badge to people who participate in a successful re-open vote) is a very dangerous idea because it would encourage people to vote to re-open bad questions that should stay closed, just so that they can earn a badge.

Comment: Cody, we keep running into each other lol

Comment: Yeh, the problem with rewarding getting questions reopened is the possibility of users deliberately posting a bad question, with a view to improving to get the badge..

Comment: Yes I didn't put the thought that people can deliberately cast reopen votes. The inverse of my idea is great and already been implemented. There is no way this can be made to work right? I get the point though.

Answer (score 0):

People do not need to be encouraged to flag to reopen closed questions. The fact that the question was closed, means it was not a good question, for a variety of reasons, including duplication.

If the owner of the question wishes to [edit and flag to reopen the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/188978/revisions), this will alert moderators. As it is not, really, the place for other users to edit the question in a way that could improve a question to a state that it could be reopened ([as such edits would be inappropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/edit-rejected-on-lisp-question/189425#189425)) there is no value in encouraging people to flag for reopen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do something like this, it should be based on people making substantial edits to a question between it being closed and reopened. Show you have actually contributed to the *why* the question is being reopened. This is a benefit to Stack Exchange.

But that will have similar "gaming the system" problems with people making edits to get the badge.

Comment: Even now we encourage the users to edit the question if there are some errors, but not changing the essence of the question, which gains them badges. I myself have seen reviewing queues with numerous "single character" changes, which people obviously do for gaining more badges.