# Poor question with an accepted invalid answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

I can't see how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719498/excel-vba-compare-copy-worksheets-from-2-excel-files/17719799#17719799) question and the accepted answer will help any future visitors. The tags are wrong, the question is poor, and the answer is in C# while the OP asked for a VBA solution. The provided link will not translate the code into VBA. I flagged it but its been declined. And on top of that [VBA != VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-and-vba).
The answer has been accepted but it does not solve the problem.

Is there anything we are going to do about it or not?
case: yes - no further explanation needed
case: no - please explain to why

Comment: How is the question tagged wrong?

Comment: if you are accepting an answer in C# then **vba** is not an appropriate tag, specifically when you are asking for a VBA code

Comment: @mehow please see the link posted above this comment, I understand exactly where you're at.. have a read of the comments etc, you'll find it helpful, I think

Comment: Tags have to do with the *question*, not the answers. He could have accepted an answer that said he should use jQuery. That would have been a *bad answer*, but it wouldn't affect the question or what tags are appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, i guess you are right about that

Comment: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: hahaha excellent

Comment: The Excel object model isn't fundamentally different, the translation is largely mechanical.  If you are a VBA or VB.NET programmer, surviving on C# code samples is a pretty essential survival skill these days.  If you don't have that skill then there isn't much point in blaming the guy that posted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downvote downvote and downvote. If you think the answer is wrong and will not help any future visitors, then downvote the post!

And please don't flag posts as *wrong*. You can comment on that answer to get explanation for his answer.

Comment: I have commented but all the comments have been removed! i have proved the answerer that he is wrong and the translated VB.NET code will not work in VBE. All comments have been removed so what else can I do while I only have 1 downvote.

Comment: Downvoting is good. But so is editing. Don't forget about that!

Comment: can't edit to change the meaning of the post Cody

Comment: @CodyGray - Yes but we can't/shouldn't edit the post to make it correct.

Comment: @hims056 agree http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/edit-rejected-on-lisp-question/189425#189425

Comment: Ok as simple as downvoting and forgetting about it. I would hate to see SO becoming a W3Schools with tons of misleading supposedly educational information. thanks for your answer hims

Comment: @mehow - Also, the meaning of downvote means it is not useful/misleading.

Comment: @hims056 yes i agree, however most of the people who come to SO from a search engine result page will most likely ignore the fact that an answers been downvoted since it's accepted and waste their time evaluating it. It may decrease SO reputation in a long run but im not the one to judge or predict.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the meaning. His argument here is that "the question is poor". Poor questions can be fixed. And there is absolutely nothing wrong with translating C# code to VB.NET (if that would help in this case, which it won't).

Comment: @CodyGray - Oh I misunderstood you. I was talking about answer. I totally agree with you.

Comment: @mehow answers at -3 and below fade to gray. Also, I always look at the score (and maybe even votes) when judging the quality of an answer I found.