# How to deal with links inside code comment?

Tags: support, edits

When I [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17960974/revisions), I removed the link inside the code comment, along with a sentence before the link:

> (Evil Steve)Because I'm a kind and wonderful person,

I was wrong to call it spam in the edit though, because I didn't check the link carefully, I thought it was some copyright statement that wasn't helpful to people reading the code.

Then OP comments on the question, saying that the sentence was permissions and username of the original code, and the link points to where the code was originally posted.

My question is: generally, should the links inside code comment be removed? And what should I do for this specific question?

Comment: edited out the ridiculous comment http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17960974/revisions with edit comment "removed unnecessary text, pls stop putting it back in"

Answer (score 1):

if they are to clarify that the code doesn't belong to them, I think they should not be removed (at the very least to be moved outside the code giving proper attribution).

unless it looks abusive, like someone pointing to his own blog in multiple times or something.

Comment: "Evil Steve" doesn't clarify anything about the code, to whom it belongs, or under what license I may use it. I checked a couple of license lists, and couldn't find that one.

Comment: Acknowledging another's work does not need to be done within the code, ever. It can be referenced within the post. Let's get real for a minute, it's not about promotion, it's about questions and answers with a view to abiding by copyright laws and not plagiarizing other's work

Comment: @Skippy "ever" is a strong word, it seems perfectly fine to have it in the code sometimes too... and I suggested this first "It can be referenced within the post"

Comment: @ajax333221 don't 'ever' use the word 'ever' again, 'never' use the words 'never' or 'ever', as they're a sure fire thing they'll be proven wrong ;) I hope you realise this is playful and not meant as an offence

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the OP could have made it clearer that this was actually identity, text, and web location of the user responsible for the original code. *However*, you as an editor do have a responsibility to not remove useful stuff; also, the consensus here is that editing the OP's code is generally off-limits. Also, with the link not *obviously* being a bad link (`sportslive.com`, for example, would be spam-flag-on-sight), couldn't you have visited and made a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search for the code? (That's what I did, and that's how I discovered that the code was legitimate.)

I think that your edit should have left the code alone, or moved the offending comment's contents outside it in such a way as to make it more obvious that it was attribution, rather than just nuking the comment. However, no major harm done here; don't beat yourself up over this one.

(I've rolled back your edit, rather than just reintroducing the attribution notice, as the rest isn't worth fixing on its own. Don't take it personally.)

Comment: Yes, removing useful stuff is a bad idea. This is what logicians call a truism, true essentially by definition. But you've failed to establish that *all* code is "useful stuff", and certainly that code *comments* are always useful. I disagree with both of these claims. In this case, the comment was entirely noise and served no apparent purpose. Calling it an "attribution notice" is absurd; I can't see any justification for interpreting it that way. We don't allow signatures on posts when they come *underneath* code blocks, why should we allow them *inside* of code blocks?

Comment: @CodyGray This wasn't the OP's signature; besides, my interpretation is that it was more an attribution notice than a signature. An unclear attribution notice, sure, but an attribution notice. Also, my wording could have been a bit clearer; I meant that to refer to the consensus that one does not simply touch OP's code. I'll clarify.

Comment: @michaelb958 I saw your roll back and I have since edited it and removed the gratuitous text. It does nothing to assist in the question or answer, nor improve the site in any way, next tile I would suggestm when rollingback or changing an edit, to fix up obvious edits cheers

Comment: @Skippy If it means anything to you, I approve of your edit.

Comment: [That's not really a consensus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187493/add-info-to-the-help-center-stating-what-not-to-edit/190641#190641), *certainly* not for code in answers. Either way, my point was that it looked and functioned just like a signature, it was just hidden in the code. Also, even the notion of attribution comments is somewhat questionable: isn't all content posted on Stack Exchange sites licensed under [CC-Wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)?

Comment: @michaelb958 that's cool, I know you from here and was surprised u didn't edit it out...