# Suggested Edit Review: Best way to reject edits to question

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Some people propose edits to source code in questions (for example, writing a name in lowercase when it should be capitalized).  Oftentimes, the issue in the code is due specifically to the problem that the edit fixes.  In those cases, I end up rejecting with reason `Invalid Edit`.  I wonder if that's the most appropriate reason.

I also suspect that it may help to edit the help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing points out that one common reason for edits is "correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages" (which makes sense for answers but not necessarily for questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Invalid Edit" is an appropriate rejection reason for someone that edits code in a question that would risk changing or "fixing" the actual problem with that code.

However, I'd say that "radical change" would be a better choice here, since you're more clearly specifying what the problem is, and that is the change in the semantic meaning of the code, and thus the question as a whole.  While I do think this is better, I still wouldn't say that "Invalid Edit" is wrong, nor would I be upset to see that as a rejection reason.

Comment: I hope that one day the help is updated to clarify that code samples in questions shouldn't be edited to fix the code

Comment: @Nirk See this feature request: [Add info to the help center stating what not to edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187493)